# Iptables udp rate limit a single ip

Tags: linux, iptables

Hello I wanted to rate limit any udp traffic coming from 1.1.1.0/24
Can anyone suggest which rule shall I use?

I searched on google and got very big scripts. But didnt get any for rate limiting a ip/subnet with just 5 packets/sec